# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil in iOS 13 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

NSDateFormatter dateFromString returned a NSDate object before iOS v13 update. But in iOS v13 and v13.1 it returns nil NSDate object. How to resolve this issue?

changing Date & Time from "Settings -> General - > Date & Time" then Unticking 24-Hour Time resolves this error.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2019-10-02 09:10:15"];
```

Expected a not nil *date

> iOS v12 and older versions didn't have this issue, setting Locale was not mandatory to get the date formatted.

Comment: If unticking 24 hour fixes the error, replace your hour unit with `hh`

Comment: @Desdenova using "hh" shows wrong time in output for afternoon times(ex: 2019-10-01 14:36:56)

Comment: Your code works for me on iOS 13.1

Comment: add a locale to your Date Formatter like `[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:[NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier]];`

Comment: @Paulw11 it works fine when the time format is not set to "24-Hour Time" in "Settings"

Comment: No, it works for me regardless of the time setting on the device.

Comment: @hyd00 setting a Locale your way solves the issue.

 I found another way too -> [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]]

Comment: @KasunRanganaMW Upvote my comment if it helped :) Thanks!

Comment: hi,@Desdenova ,encounter the same issue,can you suggest what was the solution for that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to resolve this issue.

```
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

@hyd00 setting a Locale your way also solves this issue. Thanks a lot.

```
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:[NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier]];
```